# How to check CCString is empty

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

I am using cocos2d-x and I want to check that CCString is empty or not. Since I am using box2d where i have to get fixture user data as ccsting from and check it is null or empty.

Comment: if(String != null || String.length != 0){ // perform your task}

Comment: in cocos2d-x when i am checking string==null it giving error

Comment: how to  print this value in console... if i sued like htis its printing some grbage value       CCLog(" player %s",pname->getCString());

Answer (score 0):

use `&string == null` `null` is `int` and `string` is `obj`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2/dd/d36/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_string.html), `CCString` has a member function called `length()`.